# Why it doesn't plot my fit? (And which function would you suggest to match this data?)

Tags: plotting, fitting

Could you let me know why it doesn't plot the fit?
Which function would you recommend to use to match well this data?
Thanks for your help.

```
reVData = {{4000, 0.79}, {10^4, 0.811}, {10^5, 0.849}, {10^6, 0.875}, {10^7, 0.893}, {10^8, 0.907}};
reVDataPlot = ListLogLinearPlot[reVData];
fit = FindFit[reVData, a*b^(c*x), {a, b, c}, x]
Plot[fit, {x, 10^3, 10^8}];
Show[reVDataPlot, fit]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, FindFit gives rules not a function.

Second, you have to take the logarithm of the x values for this fit.

Here is the corrected code:

```
reVData = {{4000, 0.79}, {10^4, 0.811}, {10^5, 0.849}, {10^6, 
    0.875}, {10^7, 0.893}, {10^8, 0.907}};
reVDataPlot = ListLogLinearPlot[reVData, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
fit = a + b Log[x] + c Log[x]^2 /. 
   FindFit[reVData, a + b Log[x] + c Log[x]^2, {a, b, c}, x];
plfit = LogLinearPlot[fit, {x, 10^3, 10^8}];
Show[reVDataPlot, plfit]
```

[image]

Comment: Works without logarithm too: `Show[{ListPlot[reVData, PlotRange -> All], 
  Plot[fit , {x, 10^3, 10^8}, PlotRange -> All]}, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: Many thanks @DanielHuber. Much appreciate.

Answer (score 3):

One can't expect much with fitting 4 parameters ($a$, $b$, $c$, and $\sigma$ (error standard deviation)) with just 6 data points.  In such cases one should be suspicious of a "good looking fit" and always consider prediction intervals.  (`FindFit` only gives parameter estimates.)

In this case `LinearModelFit` works and provides various goodness-of-fit criteria:

```
reVData = {{4000, 0.79}, {10^4, 0.811}, {10^5, 0.849}, {10^6, 0.875}, {10^7, 0.893}, {10^8, 0.907}};

lmf = LinearModelFit[reVData, {Log[x], Log[x]^2}, x]

Show[ListLogLinearPlot[reVData], 
 LogLinearPlot[{lmf[x], lmf["MeanPredictionBands"]}, 
  {x, Min[reVData[[All, 1]]], Max[reVData[[All, 1]]]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Gray, Gray}]]
```

[image: Data, fit and 95% prediction bands]